# Where is the stack canary stored on AArch64?

Tags: linux, arm, arm64

Is there a special space for ARM64 to store the stack canary, like the `%fs:<offset>` on x86_64? Where is the thread-local storage (TLS) stored for ARM64?

Comment: You should easily be able to find out by looking at compiler output...

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/HEAD/docs/elf-tls.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge arm64 Linux kernel is still adopting the old design with `StackGuard`, using one global canary for the whole kernel (confirmed by [this paper.](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/3374664.3375734). (Stackguard explanation is [here](https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/security-technologies-stack-smashing-protection-stackguard)). [This line of arm64 Makefile](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/arm64/kernel/Makefile#L12) seems to further confirm this.

About the second question in (arm64) [tls.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/glibc/latest/source/sysdeps/aarch64/nptl/tls.h) there is a bunch of definitions for TLS, mainly used in (arm64) [process.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/arm64/kernel/process.c).